# Way to search Airbnb by Monthly Price & Amenities with Open location?

Tags: airbnb

Is there a way to search Airbnb by Monthly Price & Amenities with Open location?

I am not looking for a specific place to go but wish to search by monthly price & amenities to see what kind of suitable priced places show up.